# Gson set SerializedName

Tags: gson, retrofit, retrofit2, serializable

I am using retrofit for making requests to my server. I am trying to use the same Model for multiple requests and I want to send different objects with different SerializedName. 
My pojo looks like this:

```
public class BaseModel<T> implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private boolean succcess;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose private T data;

    public boolean isSucccess() {
        return succcess;
    }

    public void setSucccess(boolean succcess) {
        this.succcess = succcess;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

How can I set my @SerializedName("data") in a dynamic way? Thank you all for your time!

Code sample:

```
public class BaseRequestModel<T> implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private boolean success;

    @Expose private T data;

    public boolean isSucccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSucccess(boolean succcess) {
        this.success = succcess;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

One of the objects that I am sending to BaseModel (as T data):

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    transient String requestName = "user";

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("owner_id")
    @Expose private int ownerId;

    @SerializedName("first_name")
    @Expose private String firstName;

    @SerializedName("middle_name")
    @Expose private String middleName;

    @SerializedName("last_name")
    @Expose private String lastName;

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose private String username;

    public String getRequestName() {
        return requestName;
    }

    public void setRequestName(String requestName) {
        this.requestName = requestName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(int ownerId) {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

}
```

My custom serializer:

```
public class BaseRequestCustomSerializer<T> implements JsonSerializer<User> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(User src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        src.getRequestName();
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have to pass to the serializer  instead of the specific object, since this is what my problem is all about. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Although this sounds a bit counter-intuitive to what retrofit tries to achieve in my opinion, you could try writing custom serializers. You could even have a ``transient String name`` field to be able to check easily what name should the field have.

Comment: @Fred So I should stop using SerializedName and instead of it initialize a transient String name? Can you be more specific for my case please? (I am a beginner in gson & retrofit)

Comment: Well it was just an idea, but yes. You'd get rid of ``@SerializedName`` because it effectively would not work anymore. You'd add a custom serializer to your gson - https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html - and since the ``serialize`` method receives the object you could easily have an attribute in the object that tells you which name to use in the serialization process. This attribute should not be present in the resulting json, hence you'd mark it as ``transient``. All of this does not work for deserialization... but you only mentioned the  request part.

Comment: @Fred I have implemented your method but still i have an issue, I have to pass the exact Object to the jsonSerializer, I cannot use generics (<T>), i will post a code sample in the question for more details

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set @SerializedName("data") than you must be get same variable name from api response.

Comment: if the variable name is dynamic then what will we do. like instead of "Data" it digits like 2, 3 , 8 etc.